# Dynamically searching (Similar to auto-suggest) within a jQuery Object

Tags: jquery

If I have a url that has:

```
<ul>lots of li's within</ul>
```

And On a different page I grab all the contents of that URL and store them in a jQuery object, returned via ajax.

What's the best way to then search the li elements for text that would be suitable for a search.

Work-flow example:

I have a textbox for search.. I want to add a keyup function on that textbox that searches within the jquery object, extracts anything that is close, and then insert that data into my search results box.

I know there are a lot of plugins, but was more interested in a clever way to do a simple search on the object.

Any direction is appreciated!

Comment: looks at RegExp and jQuery dom manipulation features

Comment: Look at jquery autocomplete - might solve your problem if you denote that list of `<li>`-s as your data source